# Maven - Not able to create project using maven template

Tags: java, apache, maven, maven-3

I'm trying to create maven project using maven template from command propmt. But it looks like downloading the jar and gatting failed. Maven version is 3.2.1. Please advise why this happening ?

**C:\workspace>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mkyong -DartifactId=CounterWebApp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -Dinte
ractiveMode=false**
`[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin
:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-pl
ugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.
4
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plug
in:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you working with a proxy? If so, you can check your proxy configuration in your %MAVEN_HOME%/conf/settings.xml

```
 <proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username></username>
  <password></password>
  <host></host>
  <port></port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

It´s seem that you are not able to connect to maven repository

Comment: Good, findings. What just i downloaded the maven zip from apache and setup the env.varaibles. Why is this downloading jars instead of refer the local folder ? If proxy is must , then how to define host ?